# Is there a cleaner way to typecast nested object property types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a typescript syntax for typecasting nested properties other than using nested parentheses and `as <Type>`? I do this a lot for my unit tests because I know the exact types and their order, and the nested parentheses start to get a bit unwieldly after a while. I want to maintain type checking through the entire chain, so just using `as any` isn't an option.

```js
const dog = ((((universe as Universe).planets[3] as HabitablePlanet).animalSpecies[0] as DogSpecies).breeds[0] as Poodle);
```

I'd prefer to do something like this:

```js
const dog = universe<Universe>.planets[3]<HabitablePlanet>.animalSpecies[0]<DogSpecies>.breeds[0]<Poodle>;
```

Is there a typescript syntax that already supports something like this? Or is there a way to craft a helper function that would allow me to simulate it? Like:

```js
const dog = new TypeProxy<Universe>(universe).planets.get<HabitablePlanet>(0).animalSpecies.get<DogSpecies>(0).breeds.get<Poodle>(0);
```

I've played around with proxies a bit, but couldn't get it to properly pass along the types the way I wanted.

Comment: isn't your parent object defined properly? Or why do you have to cast all properties at all?

Comment: Yes, the parent object is defined properly. Each of the collections can have multiple different object types. For example, `.animalSpecies` can have `DogSpecies`, `HorseSpecies`, `SharkSpecies`, etc. which can each have unique properties and methods.